# Differences of Delegates vs BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, delegates, backgroundworker

Can anyone explain the difference between Delegates and BackgroundWorker?In which case Backgroundworker is more efficient than Delegate?Since we are having asynchronous delegate what is the need to use BackGroungWorker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread.

[`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

> A delegate is a type that defines a method signature. ... Delegates are used to pass methods as arguments to other methods.

---

The question of which one to use has nothing to do with efficiency.

`BackgroundWorker` is a wrapper that simplifies working with threads, you can use async delegates just as well, but managing them correctly is much more difficult. Or, from MSDN:

> When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution.

Answer (score 5):

I have a brief comparison of `BackgroundWorker`, asynchronous delegates, and other approaches [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html) (from the perspective of doing background operations).

`BackgroundWorker` has these advantages:

- Progress reporting is easy. Any `BackgroundWorker` whose `WorkerSupportsProgress` property is true may report progress. The `DoWork` delegate may invoke `ReportProgress`, which causes the `ProgressChanged` event to fire.
- There's a built-in system for cooperative cancellation. The cancelling thread first calls `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync`. This causes the `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` property to become true. The `DoWork` delegate should monitor that property (checking it on a regular basis), and set `DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel` to true and return if the operation is cancelled. The `RunWorkerCompleted` delegate detects a cancelled result by checking `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled`.
- Synchronization is automatic, for both completion indications and progress reports. The `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events are synchronized to the `SynchronizationContext` that was in place when `RunWorkerAsync` was called.

Asynchronous delegates have this advantage:

- Returning a value is straightforward; it's just returned.

In conclusion, I recommend using `Task<TResult>` instead of either `BackgroundWorker` or asynchronous delegates.

Answer (score 2):

The background worker is primarily for UI work where you need to easily run a task on a background thread and provide progress updates to the screen.

One advantage is it marshalls its callbacks to the UI thread for you so you don't need to check if InvokeRequired etc.

Delegates are a more general mechanism for passing functions as arguments and by executing them asynchronously they give you an easy way of running those methods on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

*Background worker* is an abstraction to help you execute an operation on a separate thread.

*Delegates* don't really start separate threads - they are a type for referring to methods.

But what you are probably interested in is when you should use asynchronous methods instead of  using background worker.  I have not much experience in this, but [Anders Hejlsberg talked about it some in his PDC session on the Future of C#](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1b127a7d-300e-4385-af8e-ac747fee677a).

The message I got was that in some circumstances asynchronous methods would be preferable because of lower complexity.  The UI thread would still be blocked, but not for so long that it mattered.

Comment: BackgroundWorker uses the threadpool, it doesn't create its own thread.